# Unet predicts grey images (grey block)

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, google-colaboratory, unet-neural-network

I'm having problems with a unet-implementation and my data. The unet works with the testdata, but it doesn't work with my data. I only get a block of grey pixels as a prediction. I would like to use this unet for a university project. Does anybody see my fault?

here is the Repo I tried to copy: https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet

this is my Repo: https://github.com/Machuntox/unet

The membrane data is the test data and the JOSM data is for my project.

greetings,
stefan

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue?

Comment: oh yes, thanks for asking. I needed to preprocess my data differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error. I needed to preprocess my images differently. When I added the alpha channel with a value of 255, it worked. The last two steps did the trick.

See commit list: https://github.com/Machuntox/unet/commits/master/prepareData.py